# Push object to array in an update with node's mongodb package

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, push

I'm trying to update a document adding an object to an array field called subscription_history.

Object is like this:

```
{
   memberId: int,
   subscription_history: array
}
```

The code:

```
db.collection('users').update(

    {
         memberId: data.memberid
    }, {
         $push: {
             subscription_history: {
                 joined: new Date(data.joined*1000),
                 expires: new Date(data.expires*1000)
             }
         }
    }, {
         //upsert: true,
         multi: true
    }, function (err, updated) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err)
          }
    });
});
```

The query is working in mongodb client 'robomongo', but with the node.js client package is not working and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your nodes code. Without looking at what are you doing it's impossible to suggest anything.

Comment: What do you mean? the code is there

Comment: You are showing that `memberId` is an `int`. Chances are that `data.memberId` is a "string". Use `{ "memberId": parseInt(data.memberId) }` to cast to the correct type. Again it's also likely the other `data` elements are strings as well, so do the same. This is a common mistake when geting your `data` from a source such as `req.params` or `req.body` where the content of such requests is almost always a "string". If you are unsure then `console.log(data)` and add that detail to your question.

Comment: thanks i'll try that

Comment: @BlakesSeven yep, it was exactly that. Thank you very much for your help